# Инвалидация кэша

Tags: java, база-данных, кэширование

У меня есть бд, она может быть изменена руками (через php админку), а может через моё java приложение. В java предусмотрен jpo cache, но возможна такая ситуация, когда объект поменяется и в райнтайме и в бд, потому что кто-то его изменил через админку. Да, я по определённым правилам мерджу объекты, но что делать с теми потоками, которые уже взяли объект себе (невалидный) и работают с ним? Ведь их поведение уже будет неверным, потому что объект изменился.

Comment: "что делать с теми потоками, которые уже взяли объект себе (невалидный) и работают с ним?" - не брать объекты для выполнения бизнес-логики из кэша, всегда брать из БД, не держать их в памяти. В общих случаях кэш используется только для того, чтобы быстрее дать статичный ответ клиенту.

Comment: Есть тулзы типа [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/) которые синхронизируют объекты в памяти (почти) в реальном времени. Либо использовать транзакции на уровне БД и не использовать кеш.

Comment: Как тогда без кэша объекты будут работать в нескольких потоках? Ведь тогда у каждого из потоков будет свой объект. Пример, мы берём данные из бд в двух потоках (два разных коннекта к сервису) и оба потока достют кортеж и формируют объект на основе данных а потом изменяют его и коммитят в бд. Если нет кэша то изменения затрутся, потому что у каждого из потоков будет свой объект, как же тогда многопоточно работать?